# UI problem of changing color of text

Tags: front-end, bugs

**Bug introduced in 10.0.1 and persisting through 10.4.0**

---

It seems that Mathematica has some problem of changing color of text in a notebook. When I choose a color, I need to click "OK" several times before I can close the window. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Can you confirm this behavior?
I'm using Version 10.4 in OS X 10.11.4.

Comment: Confirmed on MMA 10.0.1.0 with OS X 10.10.5

Comment: Confirmed on MMA 10.3.0.0 with OS X 10.10.5

Comment: No problem with OSX 10.9.5 (mma 10.3.1, 10.4.0)